# AngularJS Array Building and Filtering

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

So in AngularJS I got a whole front-end from a vendor of ours on the condition they wouldn't have to support it. Not the best way to do business but hey it was free and does SORT of what I need. That being said. In this app it's displaying a whole bunch of data through a websocket. All the complexity of factories and what-not aside it boils down to this. An Object of arrays that is then referenced in the HTML through a few ng-repeats.

This is the object:

```
var state = 
{   queues:[],
    representatives:[],
    representative_queues:[],
    customer_clients:[],
    support_sessions:[],
    representative_support_sessions:[],
    support_session_attributes:[],
    support_session_skills:[]
};
```

It's displayed through tables like so:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table Id</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Available</th>
            <th>Skills</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="rep in state.representatives">
            <td>{{rep.id}}</td>
            <td>{{rep.username}}</td>
            <td>{{rep.user_id}}</td>
            <td>{{rep.routing_available}}</td>
            <td>{{rep.skill_code_names}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need to do though is pull various items that relate to one another because the arrays are really built much like a database schema where rep.user_id may correlate to another array.item like primary keys. As a worded example taking each rep.user_id and looping through each session.user_id for a match, if matched pull session.session_key... then match session.session_key in sessionDetails.session_key, and if that matches echo out all the items in session.Details... etc, etc... going though each of the array's and cherry picking your data based on the primary keys matching up.

Since everything is already built I was HOPING I could use some filters or ng-if structuring with all of this but frankly I'm new to AngularJS and while I know a number of languages this is proving to be very tough.

Any help would be appreciated and I can post additional code should it be needed.

**UPDATE: Here are the 2 files that drive all the data parsing and normalization into the state tables. I think the complexity issue is that because the datautil.js file drives the data in the state tables I can't use a new function to build a specific table and instead have to use filters or something else?**

dashboard.js

```
var dataUtil = require('./datautil.js');

function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}

function startsWith (string, prefix) {
    return string.slice(0, prefix.length) == prefix;
}

/*
 * Public members
 */
module.exports = {
    init: function(express, app, http, WebSocket, inIo) {
        socket = new WebSocket('');
        var handShaken = false;
        io = inIo;

        socket.on('open', function open() {
            console.log('socket is open...');
            socket.send('\ningredi state api\n');
        });

        socket.on('message', function(data, flags) {
            //console.log('received message...');
            var strData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));
            console.log('---------------------------');
            console.log(strData);
            console.log('---------------------------');

            // we have to handle cases where partial results are sent
            if (endsWith(strData,'\n')) {
                if (partialResult.length > 0) {
                    strData = partialResult + strData;
                }

                // reset partial data
                partialResult = '';
            } else {
                // append to partial result
                partialResult += strData;
                return;
            }

            var result = null;
            var handler = null;

            if (!handShaken) {
              handler = authenticate;
              handShaken = true;
            } else {
              result = JSON.parse(fixBadJson(strData));
              handler = handlers[result[0].type];
            }

            handler(result);
        });

        io.on('connection', function(socket){
            io.to(socket.id).emit('model update', {'message':'Weclome to the real-time API monitoring app'});
            socket.broadcast.emit('model update', {'message':'A user is viewing the real-time API monitoring app'})
            updateState(null, true);
            socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                io.emit('model update', {'message':'A user stopped viewing the realtime API monitoring app'});
            });
        });
    }
};

/**
 * Private members
 */
var partialResult = '';
var socket = null;
var io = null;

var state = 
{   queues:[],
    representatives:[],
    representative_queues:[],
    customer_clients:[],
    support_sessions:[],
    representative_support_sessions:[],
    support_session_attributes:[],
    support_session_skills:[]
};

var authenticate = function() {
    console.log('authenticating...');
    var msg = {
      'type' : 'authenticate',
      'credentials' : {
        'username' : 'reporting',
        'password' : ''
      }
    };
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg)+'\n');
};

var onauthenticated = function(result) {
    console.log('authenticated...');
    subscribe(result);
};

var subscribe = function() {
    console.log('subscribing...');
    var msg = {
      'type' : 'subscribe',
      'tables' : 'all'
    };
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg)+'\n');
};

var onsubscribed = function(result) {
    console.log('subscribed...');
    updateState(result, true);
};

var onmodelupdate = function(result) {
    updateState(result, true);
};

var onmodeltruncate = function() {
    state = {
        queues:[],
        representatives:[],
        representative_queues:[],
        customer_clients:[],
        support_sessions:[],
        representative_support_sessions:[],
        support_session_attributes:[],
        support_session_skills:[]
    };  
};

var updateState = function(result, sendToClient) {
  if (result != null && typeof result != 'undefined') {
    dataUtil.parseResult(result, state, io);
  }

  if (sendToClient) {
    io.emit('state change', state);
  }
};

var fixBadJson = function(json) {
  var retVal = '[' + json.trim().split('\n').join(',') + ']';
  return retVal;
};

var handlers = {
    'authenticate_response':onauthenticated,
    'subscribe_response':onsubscribed,
    'model_update':onmodelupdate,
    'model_truncate':onmodeltruncate
};
```

datautil.js

```
/*
 * Public members
 */
module.exports = {
    parseResult: function(result,state,io) {
        if (typeof result == 'undefined' || result ==  null) {
            return;
        }
        for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            var obj = result[i];

            for (var type in obj) {/* type is like insert, update, delete */
                if (type == 'type') {
                    continue;
                }
                for (var table in obj[type]) { /* table are the table names */
                    var handlerType = type + '_' + table;
                    handler = updaters[type]; /* runs the corresponding function by associating the updaters obj to 3 functions like updaters[insert]= insertTable() */
                    handler(obj[type][table],state,io,type,table);

                    io.emit('model update', {'message':'Received... ' + handlerType});
                }
            }       
        }
    }
};

var insertTable = function(obj,state,io,type,table) {
    //console.log('inserting ' + table + '...');
    var tablePlural = table + 's';
    for (var item in obj) {
        var itemExists = false;
        for (var i=0; i<state[tablePlural].length; i++) {
            var tableItem = state[tablePlural][i];
            if (tableItem.id == item) {
                itemExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!itemExists) {
            var tableObj = {};
            for (var field in obj[item]) {
                tableObj[field] = obj[item][field];
            }
            tableObj.id = item;
            state[tablePlural].push(tableObj);
        }
    }
};

var updateTable = function(obj,state,io,type,table) {
    console.log('updating ' + table + '...');
    var tablePlural = table + 's';
    for (var item in obj) {
        for (var i=0; i<state[tablePlural].length; i++) {
            var tableItem = state[tablePlural][i];
            if (tableItem.id == item) {
                for (var field in obj[item]) {
                    if (obj[item][field] != null && typeof obj[item][field] != 'undefined') {
                        //state[tablePlural][i][field] = obj[item][field];
                        tableItem[field] = obj[item][field];
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

};

var deleteTable = function(obj,state,io,type,table) {
    console.log('deleting ' + table + '...');
    var tablePlural = table + 's';
    for (var x=0; x<obj.length; x++) {
        var item = obj[x];
        for (var i=0; i<state[tablePlural].length; i++) {
            var tableItem = state[tablePlural][i];
            if (tableItem.id == item) {
                state[tablePlural].splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

var updaters = {
    'insert':insertTable,
    'update':updateTable,
    'delete':deleteTable
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the front-end.

```
    <div ng-repeat="support_session in state.support_sessions">
        <div ng-repeat="client in state.customer_clients">
            <div ng-if="client.support_session_id == support_session.id">
                <div ng-repeat="rep_session in state.representative_support_sessions">
                    <div ng-if="rep_session.support_session_id == client.support_session_id">
                        <div ng-repeat="rep in state.representatives">
                            <div ng-if="rep.id == rep_session.representative_id" class="row" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:25%">{{rep.public_display_name}} ({{rep.username}})</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:25%;background-color: #ffffff">{{client.hostname}}</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:25%">{{support_session.customer_name}}</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:25%;background-color: #ffffff">{{client.operating_system}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is something like this:
(example)

```
if rep.user_id == session.user_id then
   pull session.session_key
      if session.session_key == sessionDetails.session_key
         pull session.Details object with properties
```

or I missunderstood?
Please give me the proper information (with real variables and properties) that you need to handle and I will try to give you a hint about how to do it.

Comment: Your example is correct.The real issue is iterating without ng-repeat... or maybe I have to use nested ng-repeats... I simply don't have the Angular background to do it though.

Comment: Well I assume this is a general issue that you want to manage. One thing that I can tell you for sure is to no taking in consideration using nested ng-repats, you can do it in the back-end code. That depends on how your schema was created. You can do those relations between items directly when you create your database and then retrieve only 1 objects that contains references to other objects ( parents or childs ). What about this?

Comment: What about doing it with a series of foreach loops in the back end to build an array then just referencing the newly built array in the front end?

Comment: Well yes you can do that also, but this depends on you if in the future will be easy to understand it.

Comment: Actually I wanted to tell you from the beginning but I didn't knew how is your code

Comment: I'll update the main question with the 2 main JS files that do all the work.

Comment: To help make sense of it, the dashboard.js eventually calls the function updateState, which then call the datautil.js files "dataUtil.parseResult", the parseResult then calls 1 of 3 functions which drives the state tables to either be updated, deleted or inserted which in turn drives the front-end.So I don't know how to make this happen in the back-end with the foreach's as a result and frankly it SEEM like it should be done with loops in the front-end...

Comment: Here's a thought I had... so, in the back end after each updated, deleted or inserted have those functions call it to a function to do the foreach loops and if then's with a completely separate var, let's say, "new_state" and build that out from there, then only reference new_state in the front-end.